# Why isn't my controller passing the variable to my view from the db query in my model?

Tags: php, codeigniter

## model

```
public function cart()
{
    
    $this->load->model('Cart_model');
    $this->load->view('head');
    $data['pricing'] = $this->Cart_model->R_products();
    $this->load->view('cart', $data);
    $this->load->view('footer');    
}
```

## view

```
var_dump($data);
```

This produces error "
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: data

Filename: views/cart.php

Line Number: 4
"

However if I insert in my `VIEW`

```
$data = $this->Cart_model->R_products();
```

Then all is well. But why isn't the controller doing it's job?

## model

```
class Cart_model extends CI_Model {
    
    function R_products() 
    {

        return $this->db->get('pricing')->result();
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data['pricing'] = $this->Cart_model->R_products();
```

creates a variable called `$pricing` that you can use in your VIEW

```
var_dump($pricing);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
var_dump($pricing);
```

in your view.

Answer (score 0):

You dont get $data in the view.  Try

```
 var_dump($pricing);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using load->view($view, $data), CI always splits arrays into individual vars, so $data['pricing'] will be $pricing

Hope it helps.